# SQL: How to subtract TIME data type from two different colums and produce sum AS in HH:MM:SS

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table (TimeLog) that has 2 columns (StartTime, TIME(0), NOT NULL) and (FinishTime, TIME(0), NOT NULL)
I want write a query that will subtract (FinishTime - StartTime) AS ElapsedTime and produce the sum in HH:MM:SS

I have tried

```
SELECT StartTime
      ,FinishTime
      ,REPLACE(CAST(CAST(DATEDIFF(Hour, StartTime, FinishTime )AS VARCHAR (2)) + ':' + CAST(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, StartTime, FinishTime )AS VARCHAR(2)) + ':'
+ Cast(DATEDIFF(Second, StartTime, FinishTime )AS VARCHAR (2)) AS VARCHAR(8)),'*','00') As ElapsedTime
FROM TimeLog
```

```
StartTime   FinishTime  ElapsedTime
08:00:00    08:25:00    0:25:00
08:25:00    09:15:00    1:50:00
09:55:00    12:32:00    3:00:00
12:32:00    14:31:00    2:00:00
12:32:00    13:55:00    1:83:00
09:55:00    11:42:00    2:00:00
07:30:00    08:45:00    1:75:00
07:00:00    07:15:00    0:15:00
07:15:00    08:10:00    1:55:00
```

But this will only work if ElapsedTime is below an hour. If more than 1 hour has elapsed the result is in incorrect format as I want. Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add the seconds from `datediff()` to a date of `0` using `dateadd()`, and `convert()` that to `time(0)` data type like so:

```
select 
    StartTime
  , FinishTime
  , ElapsedTime = convert(time(0),dateadd(second,datediff(second,StartTime,FinishTime),0))
  /* for greater than 24 hours: */
  , ElapsedTime = right('0' + convert(varchar(9),(datediff(second,StartTime,FinishTime) / 3600 )),2) + ':' 
                + right('0' + convert(varchar(2),(datediff(second,StartTime,FinishTime) / 60) % 60 ),2) + ':' 
                + right('0' + convert(varchar(2),(datediff(second,StartTime,FinishTime) % 60 )),2)
from TimeLog
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/KVC7988

returns:

```
+-----------+------------+-------------+
| StartTime | FinishTime | ElapsedTime |
+-----------+------------+-------------+
| 08:00:00  | 08:25:00   | 00:25:00    |
| 08:25:00  | 09:15:00   | 00:50:00    |
| 09:55:00  | 12:32:00   | 02:37:00    |
| 12:32:00  | 14:31:00   | 01:59:00    |
| 12:32:00  | 13:55:00   | 01:23:00    |
| 09:55:00  | 11:42:00   | 01:47:00    |
| 07:30:00  | 08:45:00   | 01:15:00    |
| 07:00:00  | 07:15:00   | 00:15:00    |
| 07:15:00  | 08:10:00   | 00:55:00    |
+-----------+------------+-------------+
```

---

I believe that you may have been confused about how `datediff()` works. `datediff(second,StartTime,FinishTime)` returns number of seconds between the two times, it is not comparing the numbers in the 'seconds' place of each time.

Comment: You're absolutely correct, your code works perfectly.

Comment: in other words, (1) get the difference in terms seconds (2) add that difference to 1900-01-01 then (3) get the time from the sum (datetime) . brilliant!

Comment: Just be aware (for future readers) this doesn't work for an interval that exceeds 24 hours.

Comment: @SqlZim How would I add find the total ElapsedTime of multiple rows?

Comment: @DRUIDRUID I have updated the demo to show an example where the total elapsed time is calculated using the `sum()` of elapsed seconds:  `convert(time(0),dateadd(second,sum(datediff(second,StartTime,FinishTime)),0))`

Comment: @SqlZim should have asked here... to show elapsed time of multiple rows and time is more than 24 hours the result is incorrect. How could we allow more than 24 in the HH space. I have changed StartTime and FinishTime to varchar....any advice

Comment: @DRUIDRUID I have updated my answer and the rextester demo to show how you might calculate this for intervals that may exceed 24 hours.